# How could I play a shoutcast/icecast stream using HTML5?

Tags: html, streaming, audio-streaming, shoutcast, icecast

Is it possible to play a shoutcast/icecast stream using HTML5?

If so, how should I implement it?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

#### 2020 update

Modern browsers don't need any special treatment or server-side workarounds to play audio. Simply use an audio tag with a direct link to one or more stream sources (**not** a playlist):

```
<audio>
    <source src="http://relay.publicdomainradio.org/classical.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio):

> The **HTML `<audio>` element** is used to embed sound content in documents. It may contain one or more audio sources, represented using the `src` attribute or the `<source>` element: the browser will choose the most suitable one.

Browsers support `flac`, `mp3`, `vorbis`, `aac`, `opus` and `wav`. More details on [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=audio).

#### Original post

Add a semicolon to the end of the http request. It IS the protocol set forth by shoutcast to override it's browser detection. Like this:

```
<audio controls src="http://shoutcast.internet-radio.org.uk:10272/;"></audio>
```

Comment: It appears, that nowadays (2020) the audio element can handle mp3 streams without any tweaks.

Answer (score 18):

There is a big problem with SHOUTcast, which I suspect is responsible for it not working even in Chrome which is supposed to support MP3.

SHOUTcast can serve three different types of response:

- a native-SHOUTcast “ICY” protocol streaming audio response. It decides to do this if the player accessing the stream includes an `icy-metadata: 1` header.
- a plain-HTTP streaming audio response, without extra metadata, for media players with no ICY support.
- the “SHOUTcast D.N.A.S. Status” page and other pages on the web interface.

How does it decide whether to serve a web page instead of an audio stream? It guesses whether you're using a web browser. By looking to see whether the `User-Agent` header starts with `Mozilla/...`. Because all web browsers are Mozilla, right? Jeez, SHOUTcast.

So when Chrome tries to fetch the audio stream to play, SHOUTcast thinks it's a web browser (well... it is) and refuses to give it the audio stream to put in the audio tag. Instead it gets the admin web page.

(I would guess Safari is passing the `icy-metadata` header to avoid the problem, having specific support for SHOUTcast. I can't test it at the moment as Safari won't play audio or video. Maybe it wants me to install QuickTime for that. Maybe it can go get stuffed.)

So you'll probably need to add a Flash audio player as fallback.

Comment: thank you very much for not only saying that it's not working but also explaining why!

Answer (score 5):

```
<audio src="http://85.25.108.20:8090/;" controls autoplay></audio>
```

This should work fine, but make sure `/;` is there after the stream URL and port. If you don't need autoplay, remove the **"autoplay"** tag.

Comment: I edited you post slightly, please try to use proper grammar when you post on Stack Overflow. Other than that, good job!

Comment: Why is `/;` necessary?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. But its only work in Safari

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<audio controls src="http://shoutcast.internet-radio.org.uk:10272/"></audio>
```

Cause Opera and Firefox did not support non free Codecs

Answer (score 3):

see here: [Is it possible to play shoutcast internet radio streams with html5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229118/is-it-possible-to-play-shoutcast-internet-radio-streams-with-html5)

Answer (score 0):

On redirecting problems with `<audio`> tag in Browsers try to add "/stream" at the end of the stream URL for preventing redirecting.

example:

not working:
http://live-radio01.xxxxxx.com/2TJW/mp3

working:
http://live-radio01.xxxxxx.com/2TJW/mp3/stream

Answer (score 0):

I use Icecast with Easystream for streaming to both mac and pc.  A Script Sets up the audio player called MP3 Sticky Player. swf
With the documentation support files the player just loads as below in both cases.

PC

```
<ul id="playlist" style="display:none;">
        <li data-path="http://99.250.117.109:8000/stream" data-thumbpath="thumbnail of whatever" data-downloadable="no" data-duration="00:00">
    </li>
</ul>
```

MAC

```
<audio style="width: 100%" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay" src="http://99.250.117.109:8000/stream">
            Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
</audio>
```

As we have removed images from any mp3 metadata we use a image loader that grabs the Icy-MetaData (FYI you will need at least PHP 5.4 to run correctly) and matches a directory of cover art for each players song that streams.

Answer (score 0):

On Chrome 9x If your website works over https Your link for shoutcast stream url must be a https url, for example:

```
<audio controls src='https://ssl-1.radiohost.pl:7028/stream' type='audio/mpeg' align='cemnter'>
                     Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
```