# Universal way to listen IceCast via mobile web browser

Tags: android, ios, flash, mobile, icecast

i need to create mobile webpage when everyone can listen our IceCast internet radio. I tried:

1. Flash Icecast player - but it does'nt work on iOS
2. Direct linkt to sream, eg.: http://play.radiopanteon.pl:8000/stream but it does'nt work on: Mobile Opera and Android browser.
3. HTML5 Audio tag, but it does'nt work on Mobile Opera, and Chrome (on Sony Xperia M)

Is there a universal way to listen internet radio via web page ? 
Sorry for my poor english ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How could I play a shoutcast/icecast stream using HTML5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743279/how-could-i-play-a-shoutcast-icecast-stream-using-html5)

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229118/is-it-possible-to-play-shoutcast-internet-radio-streams-with-html5

Comment: No! That is useless for me. I'm looking for something that works, when html5 audio tag does'nt work !

Answer (score 0):

There is no universal solution to what you ask for. Especially on mobile devices.
Your best bet is an amalgamated solution like they already exist.
HTML5 audio as first step and detect if the browser supports that in Javascript. If it doesn't, check Flash (very unlikely combination nowadays on mobile devices). Failing that display links to playlist files and instructions how to download an app that can play this stream.

Answer (score 0):

I run a service that streams mp3's via icecast to browsers and apps - the best solution is as TBR states - start with HTML 5 and work backwards - you could look into using http://mediaelementjs.com/ which takes a lot of the work out of it - however you need to stream in a format that is acceptable to the widest majority of devices, mp3 seems most appropriate there.

Perhaps that will point you in the right direction (if you havent found the way already!)