# Shoutcast stream buffering with Adobe AIR without using Flash/Flex player?

Tags: javascript, streaming, air, shoutcast

My application is written in Adobe Air & JavaScript and doesn't use Flash/Flex.
`Air.Sound()` is used to play (shoutcast) audio streams.
I'm looking for a solution (**without using external Flash/Flex** players, coz) that can preload (buffer) a few second of audio stream to avoid playback lags and keeping memory usage low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know Air 2.5 added Audio and Video html5 tags.

For shoutcast and html 5 audio see  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229118/is-it-possible-to-play-shoutcast-internet-radio-streams-with-html5ml)

**Edit: Apparently AIR left out the audio/video tags (because they are an alternative to flash and you get flash on AIR - the way adobe looks at it). So I think the answer is you can't do it without flash. Even if it had the audio tag you'd most probably need to tweak the output streams from the server.**