# Sky.fm live stream with HTML5 audio

Tags: html, html5-audio

http://u10.sky.fm/ displays the audio URLs and types. It is powered by www.icecast.org.

I have the following code snippets HTML5

```
<audio controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
  <source src="http://u10.sky.fm/altrock" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

Unfortunately, it does not work. I am using Chrome. What did I do wrong?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT: Updated code below still does not work.

```
<audio controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
  <source src="http://u10.sky.fm:80/sky_altrock" />
</audio>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the contents of the m3u file.
use this as src:
http://u10.sky.fm:80/sky_altrock

Comment: Thanks for your help. I downloaded the m3u file and use http://u10.sky.fm:80/sky_altrock. Unfortunately, it still does not work.

Comment: sorry, I really thought that would fix it. the html5 code looks good. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229118/is-it-possible-to-play-shoutcast-internet-radio-streams-with-html5 is a discussion on live streams.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for your help. I tried it on Firefox Minefield. It does not work. http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#reference-html5-audio says that audio stream fails on Chrome.

Comment: I have just reported the issue to the Chrome team. Please see http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=69878

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding semicolen at the end of stream url to make the shoutcast play in html5 player:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<audio controls src="http://baldyradio.com:8010/;"></audio>
```

And , i noticed the stream url you mentioned is not working now. try some good stream url.