# HTML5 Audio Element Closing connection when passing URL as src

Tags: html, audio, https, html5-audio

TL;DR bolded question at the bottom

So I've spent the better part of the day trying to figure out if I can link a streaming URL to the HTML5 Audio element, and I couldn't tell from the spec. This line from the spec (when describing the `audio` element was interesting:

```
src — Address of the resource
```

And so it doesn't look like it has to be a static path. However, everything else I've read from SO answers, to different parts of the spec, it was inconclusive, so I just decided to try it. I grabbed different streams off this website: https://lrn.fm/listen/online/ and decided to just stick things in the audio src. Here is my code for the audio element:

```
<audio src='https://streams.lrn.fm:8110' controls></audio>
```

And this is the error message I get in the JS console in Chrome 71 on Mac Mojave (running a test webserver on XAMPP with the default configs pretty much):

```
GET https://streams.lrn.fm:8110/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
```

This is the error message I get when I replace the above `src` with this src (https://s2.voscast.com:7392):

```
GET https://s2.voscast.com:7392/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

So it doesn't look like the audio element accepts a streaming URL as a source. Is this true, or am I doing something wrong?

To me, it looks like the browser won't accept anything over a non-standard port when GETting over HTTPS. Is that way off base? Pretty much, this is the question:

**Does the HTML5 Audio element accept a remote server address in the `src` attribute?**

Answer (score 1):

you have just made a simple miskate.

**Your code**

```
  <audio src='https://streams.lrn.fm:8110' controls></audio>
```

**Updated code**

```
<audio controls>
          <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
          <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>
```

You just need to put the right url which contains the valid extension. like - .mp3, .ogg and type of the media.

Hope this helpful.

Code Snippet here.

```html
  <audio controls>
              <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
              <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
            Your browser does not support the audio element.
            </audio>
```

Comment: The funniest thing is that for me, it works only like this: ```<audio preload="auto" src="..." controls></audio>```. I'm using signed urls and using other formats, the source link get broke in many lines by browser, so it mess the whole tag.

Answer (score 0):

On a quick look from the [HTML issue](https://github.com/w3c/html/issues/1670):

There is nothing in the spec that would block this, although I think implementations are free to reject connections, especially if they don't handle the given media type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use streaming URls in the audio element. See:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/33512389/1127699
- [How could I play a shoutcast/icecast stream using HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743279/how-could-i-play-a-shoutcast-icecast-stream-using-html5)
- http://www.martinjhiggins.co.uk/html5-audio-with-shoutcast/

I was unable to access the specific streams you mentioned. I suspect the owner of them has applied restrictions so they can only be loaded from their own pages. Are you able to load those streams directly in your browser?

Try running your own streaming server - or find a free source of streaming audio.