# Playing live streaming .wav file in HTML

Tags: html, audio, streaming, web-audio-api

I have a .wav file that is being continuously appended to. Is it possible to play this file using the HTML `<audio>` element? Here is my current approach:

```
<audio controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay" preload>
  <source src="stream.wav/" type="audio/wav">
</audio>
```

If I refresh the page, it reflects the new audio available in the file, but it does not render as a streaming player. It seems like it should be playing in "live" mode according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978301/html5-audio-livestreaming).

I would also be open to using some kind of framework or JavaScript to accomplish this if that would be best practice, but I haven't found anything yet.

Comment: What program is adding to the WAV file? That data might have to be put into something like gstreamer or ffpmeg to get started.

Answer (score 2):

Files cant end in `/`

`src="stream.wav/"`

Should be `src="stream.wav"`

Comment: That does not appear to make it reflect as a live stream. Is there anything else you would suggest trying?

Comment: I'm thinking that maybe the premise is flawed -- I'm expecting that simply updating my .wav file as I have new frames to add will accomplish this, and I'm guessing there's something else I need to do to make the HTML recognize it as a live stream.

Answer (score -1):

In order to stream live audio and video, you will need to run specific streaming software on your server or use third-party services.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_delivery/Live_streaming_web_audio_and_video#Server-side_Streaming_Technologies

That section of that page lists a few popular options for doing this.