# Detect support for Shoutcast ICY MP3 without navigator.userAgent in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, mp3, html5-audio, shoutcast, browser-feature-detection

The current version of Mozilla Firefox is 23.0.1, this version does not support [play MP3 shoutcast streams from a TCP port different to 80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17014317/playing-mp3-shoutcast-streams-with-html5-audio-in-firefox) (most common is 8000 for Shoutcast 1.9.8).

I use Flash when MP3 support is not available in HTML5 audio, the way to detect is:

```
try{
    var a = document.createElement('audio');
    r = !!(a.canPlayType && !!a.canPlayType("audio/mpeg; codecs=mp3").replace(/^no$/,''))
}catch(e){
    r = false;
}
```

The support for Mp3 shoutcast streams in [Firefox will be added in version 24](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=869725).

a.canPlayType("audio/mpeg; codecs=mp3") = probably in Chrome and Firefox, Chrome really support, firefox does not support, due to this the current code to detect not work for Firefox.

The current version of jQuery that support IE 6 is 1.10.2, this version does not has .browser

I think the "stylized" way is testing features and not querying for browsers / versions, notwithstanding here I see hard not to violate this "principle".

What is the "stylized" way of detect MP3 ICY support without navigator.userAgent in Firefox?

Comment: The problem doesn't have to do with MP3, but with the `ICY` in the status line of the server response.  There is no way to detect this, as it isn't a real specification and browsers only support it because they follow the "accept anything" approach in most cases.  The way around the problem is to use something that returns a real HTTP response, such as Icecast.  If you want, I am testing a hosting service over at http://audiopump.co, and can relay your SHOUTcast stream.  Shoot me an e-mail at brad@audiopump.co.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no sophisticated way to detect it. The good news is the last stable Firefox 24.0 support play shoutcast streams in MP3 with HTML5 audio. The best way to detect the support that I wrote:

```
function icy(){
    try{
        if(!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident\/7\./) && $.browser.mozilla && $.browser.version < 24)
            return false;//https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=869725
        var a = document.createElement('audio');
        r = !!(a.canPlayType && !!a.canPlayType("audio/mpeg; codecs=mp3").replace(/^no$/,''))
    }catch(e){
        r = false;
    }
    return r;
}
```

If you use the lastest [jQuery 1.10.2](http://jquery.com/download/), you need include [jQuery Migrate plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme) to use $.browser