# <audio> element with controls' trackbar not moving

Tags: php, html, audio, html5-audio

I have an `<audio>` element with controls like so:

```
<audio controls="controls" id="audio-sample" preload="auto">
    <source src="../../music-sample.php?type=ogg&amp;id=<?php echo $item->custom_5; ?>" type="audio/ogg" />
    <source src="../../music-sample.php?type=mp3&amp;id=<?php echo $item->custom_5; ?>" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
```

The player shows up, and the sound plays just fine, but the trackbar doesn't move to reflect the elapsed time, and it can't be dragged to seek. Why not? Do I need to send some sort of additional header? This is all the relevant PHP, nothing special:

```
header('Content-Type: ' . $mimetype[$type]);

$file = fopen($filename, 'rb');
fpassthru($file);
fclose($file);
exit();
```

[You can see the problem live here.](http://www.musiklus.com/anthology/item/1516/a-companion-on-the-road-words-by-sheelah-megill)

Comment: What's the advantage of explicitly sending the file's contents over just `readfile()`?

Comment: @alex: None, I didn't know `readfile` existed. Thanks! (And I'll try the `Content-Length` thing now. I don't think it worked once upon a time, but who knows!)

Comment: @alex: `Content-Length` worked perfectly. Arrgh, sorry! Please post that as an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the `Content-Length` header...

```
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filename));
```

For some reason without that info up front, it can't do the necessary math to place the track bar.

Comment: Actually, although you can still seek on Firefox (in the area that's already played), the track thumb starts and stays at the end of the bar. Any ideas?

Comment: @minitech I'm not sure sorry, I haven't used the `audio` element too much. I'll have a look though.

Comment: As Apache is replacing the Content-Length header with Transfer-Encoding: chunked; I am unable to get the seek bar working. Any approach to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

The trick to getting it working on Firefox and Safari specifically is to send a `Content-Range` header, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3300910/707111).

```
$length = filesize($filename);

header('Content-Type: ' . $mimetype[$type]);
header('Content-Length: ' . $length);
header('Content-Range: bytes 0-' . ($length - 1) . '/' . $length);

readfile($filename);
```

Comment: I just ran in to this, and it looks like `header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');` resolved the problem for me! I got clued on to this from your question related to this issue. Clearly, there are some implementation issues in all the user agents :(

Answer (score 1):

### My Experience

There is nothing wrong with your code. I had this issue once and .. And it was a simple cache issue on `Firefox` and `Content-Length` which you have discovered

`c.php`

```
<audio controls="controls" id="audio-sample" preload="auto">
    <source src="a.php?type=ogg&id=0" type="audio/ogg" />
    <source src="a.php?type=mp3&id=1" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
```

`a.php`

```
$id = intval($_GET['id']);
$files = array(0 => "audio.ogg",1 => "audio.mp3");
$filename = $files[$id];

header('Content-Type: ' . mime_content_type($filename));
header("Content-transfer-encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filename));

ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($filename);
exit();
```

This worked `100%` in Firefox but when i changed `readfile($filename)` to

```
  readfile("SIMPLE ERROR ERROR");
```

Firefox sill pays the audio for me instead of not paying any file the only way to make it realize the mistake was to add a random string to the `src` file

```
<source src="a.php?type=ogg&id=0&<?php echo mt_rand(); ?>" type="audio/ogg" />
                                             ^---- rand string
```

This way the URL was requested Firefox stooped playing the audio instantly

### The Problem

Because you have tried to stream the content before with `Zero Content-Length` that is sill the reason your audio is not paying ..... Firefox has cached the initial invalid content

### Solution

Clear all your cache .. with the following code above your code should work fine or just add the rand parameter in your code for testing

[image]

### Invalid Relative Position

Permanently using `mt_rand()` would make it difficult for `Firefox` to cache the audio file which results in Invalid Relative solution.

Remove the `mt_rand` after the cleaning of cache and this would be fixed

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed part of it! But now it shows the current position relative to what's buffered so far, and it doesn't seem to want to buffer all of it in advance, just about one second. Any ideas?

Comment: Firefox only has valid relative position for cache audio files  ... If you play the audio the second time you would notice that the relative position becomes fixed ... Solution .. remove the mt_rand and you are fine ....

Comment: I didn't add a random number for testing - it still only shows the position relative to the first five seconds or so.

Comment: @minitech ... after playing the audio for the second time does it do the same ?

Comment: Use `<source src="audio.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />` without PHP and check if it does the same .. What version of firefox are you using

Answer (score 1):

A combination of `Content-Type = audio/ogg`, `Content-Length`, `Accept-Ranges = bytes`, and **most importantly, I think** the `X-Content-Duration` response headers is what has worked for me.

The `X-Content-Duration` header tells clients what the duration of an ogg file is, in seconds.  Here's some more info about it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Configuring_servers_for_Ogg_media.

Each frame of an ogg file might be encoded with a variable number of bits, so just knowing the file size in bytes doesn't tell you the file length in seconds.  You can tell clients this explicitly for ogg vorbis files with the `X-Content-Duration` header.