# Html audio player audio stops in the middle

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, html5-audio

I am using simple html audio player here:

```
  <source src="TestFile.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
```

Works fine in windows, mac safari. Also works fine in IPhone5s.

But works partially in higher version of iPhone device (iPhone 7).  Audio stops in the middle of the audio.

For Example if audio duration is 1.45 min. Audio stops in 1.01 min.

Please share any other suggestion.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could anyone share your knowledge on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We got the answer from after lot of surfing in online for the issue related to audio player not playing the audio completely

[HTML5 <audio> Safari live broadcast vs not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995589/html5-audio-safari-live-broadcast-vs-not)

We have applied the accepted and it seems to be working fine