# Timing problem for generated audio in some browsers

Tags: php, apache, audio, safari, html5-audio

I need to generate audio from an mp3 file. So I use curl library to get the file, then set required headers, and `echo` the audio content.

The problem is that it does not work correctly in Chrome and Safari browsers. The audio files being loaded, and starts playing, but you can't change the time(can't set `.currentTime` in javascript, also in browser the timing slider does not work). (In Firefox works fine).

The code: php

```
            $agent = 'stagefright/1.2 (Linux;Android 5.0)';
            $url = 'http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-07-Bubble.mp3';

            $ch = curl_init($url);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1) ;
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.jplayer.org/');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);

            $media = curl_exec($ch);

            curl_close($ch);

            $content_length = strlen($media);
            $type = "audio/mpeg";

            header("Content-type: ".$type);
            header("Content-length: ".$content_length);

            echo $media;

            exit;
```

Any ideas?

Maybe I miss some php headers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I guess, I was missing a php header.

Need to add the following header:

```
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
```

Hope that will help somebody.

UPDATE:

I found a very similar question here: [HTML5 <audio> Safari live broadcast vs not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995589/html5-audio-safari-live-broadcast-vs-not)

Adding the `Accept-Ranges` header fix the issue for chrome. But for safari you need to check for `HTTP_RANGE` and add `Content-Range` header.

Here is my implementation, which works fine in all major browsers.

```
        $content_length = strlen($media_total);
        $total_bytes = $content_length;
        $content_length_1 = $content_length - 1;

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {

            $byte_range = explode('-',trim(str_ireplace('bytes=','',$_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])));

            $byte_from = $byte_range[0];
            $byte_to = intval($byte_range[1]);
            $byte_to = $byte_to == 0 ? $content_length_1 : $byte_to;

            $media_total = substr($media_total,$byte_from,$byte_to);

            $content_length = strlen($media_total);

            header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
        }
        else {
            $byte_from = 0;
            $byte_to = $content_length_1;
        }

        $content_range = 'bytes '.$byte_from.'-' . $byte_to . '/' . $total_bytes;

        header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
        header("Content-Range: ".$content_range);
        header("Content-type: ".$type);
        header("Content-length: ".$content_length);
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

        echo $media_total;

        exit;
```