# Rails 3.1 : How to download a PDF housed on Linode to client computer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, download

I am trying to understand what needs to be done to initiate a download 
of files that are housed on a server different from the one on which the Rails app is?

Specifically, my Rails app is on Heroku and the PDFs I want to make available for 
download are on Linode. I would like the client to get the PDFs when he/she clicks 
on a download button  in the web-app

My first attempt was with send_file :type => 'application.pdf', :x_sendfile => true.
But this is obviously wrong because it can only serve files stored locally on the web-app server

1. Is there, therefore, a way to get Linode to send data directly to the client? , OR
2. Do I have to download the file locally and then call send_file ? (yuck!!!)
3. Would any changes be required on the Linode end? I have a web-service running there on Tomcat

Thanks in advance for your help,
Abhinav

Answer (score 0):

You can try reading the file into a data stream and using send_data. Here is a [Ruby forum discussion](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/98626) of a similar idea. The post also describes your yuck options (#2, local download). Unfortunately I cannot speak to Linode changes.

Also, here is an [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322030/using-send-file-to-a-remote-source-ruby-on-rails) about a similar issue.