# rails 3.1 : why isn't redirect_to initiating a file download?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, download

I have some PDF files on a remote server (Apache + Tomcat) different from the one on which the Rails app is. And I want users to be able to download them after clicking OK on a "Save As" dialog box

So, in my controller, I have an action to process download requests. This action simply redirects_to 
the URL of the PDF. Problem is that the "Save as" dialog box does not open up

```
def download
  url = "#{server}/...../file.pdf"
  redirect_to url
end
```

However, if I were to take the fully qualified URL for the PDF and insert it into the browser's address bar, then the desired behaviour happens

There is obviously a difference between the 2 requests. I haven't - because I don't know how to - set Content-disposition or Content-type, for example. Or perhaps, redirect_to is simply the wrong way to go

And so I am hoping someone here could help me understand why :

1. the "obvious" solution - using redirect_to - is not working
2. Why (1) might not be the preferred option and options like send_file are what are suggested more often.
3. If send_file is the way to go, then I would need to bring the file first to my Rails server before calling send_file. How can I do that?

Comment: So what -does- it do now? just bring you to the pdf in your browser?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 3.1 : How to download a PDF housed on Linode to client computer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109927/rails-3-1-how-to-download-a-pdf-housed-on-linode-to-client-computer)

Comment: Varatis -> As far as I can tell, nothing much is happening. I get "Redirected to <url>" and "Completed 302 Found in 126ms" messages, but no "Save as" dialog box. The Response Header in Firebug has Location set to the correct URL. But Content-type is text/html - which I guess should be application/pdf. Would setting headers[Content-type] help? At any rate, I don't know where the difference b/w the 2 calls - redirect_to from Rails app and direct call from the browser - lies

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
def download
  url = "#{server}/...../file.pdf"
  send_file url, :type=>"application/pdf"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Content-Disposition` header to attachment with the filename that you wish the user to download the file as. Something like this ...

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="fname.ext"
```

Answer (score -1):

This works:

```
  def sendfile(path)
    headers["Location"] = path
    redirect_to(path)         
  end
```

Comment: Reed -> If I see the Response header in Firebug, then Location is set to  the correct URL. In that case, would the above be necessary? On the other hand, the Content-type is 'text/html' - which is obviously wrong. Shouldn't that be the one to change ?