# Is there a way to download a file from s3 using the ruby gem aws-s3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, amazon-s3

Ok so i tried two methods both failed

First method using the [aws-s3](http://amazon.rubyforge.org/) gem

```
require 'aws/s3'
S3ID = "MYACCESS"
S3KEY = "MYKEY"
include AWS::S3
AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(
  :access_key_id     => S3ID,
  :secret_access_key => S3KEY
)

bucket = AWS::S3::Bucket.find("test_bucket")
 => #<AWS::S3::Bucket:0x007fea3e2898c8 @attributes={"xmlns"=>"http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/", "name"=>"test_bucket", "prefix"=>nil, "marker"=>nil, "max_keys"=>1000, "is_truncated"=>true}, @object_cache=[#<AWS::S3::S3Object:0x70322020960960 '/test_bucket/00000188110119_1000000731213/'>, #<AWS::S3::S3Object:0x70322020960660 '/test_bucket/00000188110119_1000000731213/10_08-52-08.mp3'>, #<AWS::S3::S3Object:0x703220209

bucket.size
 => 1000 

bucket.objects[0]
 => #<AWS::S3::S3Object:0x70322028046080 '/test_bucket/00000188110119_1000000731213/'> 
bucket.objects[1]
 => #<AWS::S3::S3Object:0x70322028046040 '/test_bucket/00000188110119_1000000731213/10_08-52-08.mp3'> 
bucket.objects[1].key
 => "00000188110119_1000000731213/10_08-52-08.mp3" 

File.open("/Users/matt/local_copy.mp3", "w") do |f|
  f.write(bucket.objects[1])
end
```

**UPDATE**

```
bucket.objects[1]
 => #<AWS::S3::S3Object:0x70322028046040 '/test_bucket/00000188110119_1000000731213/10_08-52-08.mp3'> 
bucket.objects[1].read
 NoMethodError: undefined method `read' for #<AWS::S3::S3Object:0x70322028046040>
bucket.objects[1].class
 => AWS::S3::S3Object
```

As you can see what i am trying to do is copy the mp3 from the s3 bucket and copy it to the local computer....any ideas on how to do this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Send\_File to a Remote Source (Ruby on Rails)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322030/using-send-file-to-a-remote-source-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See :
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/S3Object.html

Basically you have to use the `read` and `write` methods on S3 objects.

So :

```
File.open("/Users/matt/local_copy.mp3", "w") do |f|
  f.write(bucket.objects[1].read)
end
```

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `read' for #<AWS::S3::S3Object:0x007fac0e8b4590>

Comment: OK, that's because you're using the VERY VERY old S3 gem, this gem is clearly outdated. You should use the official AWS SDK gem from Amazon.

Comment: The documentation for the official gem is here : http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/frames.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8977/discussion-between-tamer-and-slainer68)

Comment: If you get Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 , try adding 'wb' instead of 'w' for the permissions

Answer (score 0):

If you are not forced to use the gem 'aws-s3', you might want to check out `fog`, which does basically the same things, only it is agnostic regarding the backend (aws, rackspace, ..), and seem to be more active. At the bottom of [this page](http://fog.io/1.1.2/storage/) there's an example showing what you want to achieve