# Creating a Rails Music Player App (something like Rdio)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, streaming

i want to create a rails app that has a lot of mixtapes, which the user can listen to and download (like datpiff.com). All the mixtapes would be uploaded by me. Each mixtape would have  their own page, with the title, artist name, cover, etc.

I'm having trouble getting the architecture of the app right. What's the best way to upload all the mixtapes. (I'm thinking something like Amazon S3).

Do I have to upload a zipped file with the entire mixtape, and each individual song, or just the zipped file.

How do i show the information of each song (title, length, etc)

Ofcourse the biggest problem is the streaming of the mixtape, and the download of the file.

Can anyone guide me as to whats the best way to create this app. (Is Rails the best way to do it?)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're on the right track with S3. Use [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) in conjunction with it if you want to make some sort of GUI for you to upload stuff with.

For streaming check out [jPlayer](http://jplayer.org/), which is a jQuery plugin.

Download's no biggie. Check out [Rails' send file](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_file). For sending from a remote source like S3, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322030/using-send-file-to-a-remote-source-ruby-on-rails).