# Sinatra: How to respond with an image with headers "content-type" => "image/jpeg"

Tags: image, sinatra, content-type

**Example:**

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/somekey' do
  headers('Content-Type' => "image/jpeg")
  ["http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/23/Lake_mapourika_NZ.jpeg", "http://img.brothersoft.com/screenshots/softimage/j/jpeg_converter-4567-1.jpeg"].sample
end
```

I want to respond with an image that is not hosted on my server.

How would I get about this?

Note:
The link to the image is not secret (as it is hosted on S3). It is for a site that generates identicons.

Checkout [http://identico.in/[insert_any_key_here]](http://identico.in/some_random_key). The reason is I wanted the server to do a look up, if the image already exists on S3, use that one, if not, generate one and then upload it to s3.

Note:
If I did:

```
require "open-uri"
open ["http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/23/Lake_mapourika_NZ.jpeg", "http://img.brothersoft.com/screenshots/softimage/j/jpeg_converter-4567-1.jpeg"].sample
```

Then it works, however, I feel that this might be a lot slower because my server first has to download the image and open it and then the user has to download the image from my server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes, if you want to send from your server, you need to have it on your server before sending. So most of the time you need to use `send_file open('link')` and be a proxy from storage server and a client.

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'open-uri'

get '/' do
  send_file open('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/23/Lake_mapourika_NZ.jpeg'),
        type: 'image/jpeg',
        disposition: 'inline'
end
```

But if a link is not a secret, you can just render some javascript and it will open image in browser.

```
require 'sinatra'
get '/' do
  "<script>document.location = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/23/Lake_mapourika_NZ.jpeg'</script>
end
```

Comment: Hi Ivan, thanks for your response. However, javascript wouldn't work as I would like the client to be able to use it inside their html such as "<img src="identico.in/somekey"/>". Please see my updated question

Comment: ok, I see, and here are some more options. As you use S3, you can take a look for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322030/using-send-file-to-a-remote-source-ruby-on-rails this answer. It will give you some ideas how to serve files from s3.
More that that, you can send file as it is generated and after that send it to S3 in other thread.