# What is the process by which sinatra's send_file decides what content-type to use?

Tags: http, sinatra, content-type, sendfile

What is the process by which sinatra's send_file decides what content-type to use?

For example, it seems that it works by the extension of the file passed to send_file, so if it is send_file blah.txt . then when I http to the route, I will get/ the response header will be, `content-type: text/plain`, so any html in the txt file will be interpreted by the web browser as plain text. Whereas if the file is blah.html then the server will respond with `content-type: text/html`.(and any html in the file is rendered as such)

And of course the route name is irrelevant so you could go to `http://127.0.0.1:4567/zzz.html` and it could lead to send_file a.txt and a.txt may contain html tags but since it's a `.txt` file send_file will cause sinatra to respond with `content-type: text/plain` and the browser won't render any html sent and will show it as plain text.  I may be wrong but that seems to be what my quick tests indicate. Where I tried different routes, different filename extensions(.txt, and .html), sometimes files with html in them sometimes not, seeing whether the browser renders the html or not, and seeing what the content-type header was, with wget -d.

So then my question related to that is, is there a list that sinatra's send_file function uses, that relates file extension to content-type?  I would like to see that list.   And if not, then what is the process it is using.

Note- I understand there is a way to pass in a content-type [Sinatra: How to respond with an image with headers "content-type" => "image/jpeg"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20275841/sinatra-how-to-respond-with-an-image-with-headers-content-type-image-jpeg)
  but i'm asking how/ by what method, send_file determines content-type when no content-type is passed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is the `send_file` method](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v2.0.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L373) in the Sinatra framework (currently v2.0.5), notice it hands off finding out the content type straight away if none has been set:

```
if opts[:type] or not response['Content-Type']
  content_type opts[:type] || File.extname(path), :default => 'application/octet-stream'
end
```

[The `content_type` method](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/2.0.7/lib/rack/mime.rb#L16) will either return immediately or hand off to `mime_type`, which is a delegate of [Rack's `mime_type` method](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/2.0.7/lib/rack/mime.rb#L16) (currently v2.0.7). This uses a well known list of extensions to check against.

```
def mime_type(ext, fallback='application/octet-stream')
  MIME_TYPES.fetch(ext.to_s.downcase, fallback)
end
```

The list begins [on line 49](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/2.0.7/lib/rack/mime.rb#L49):

```
MIME_TYPES = {
  ".123"       => "application/vnd.lotus-1-2-3",
  ".3dml"      => "text/vnd.in3d.3dml",
  ".3g2"       => "video/3gpp2",
  ".3gp" => "video/3gpp",
  # <snip>
```

As you can see from the `content_type` snippet, the default it falls back on is `application/octet-stream`.